# If Cauchy's functional equation is continuous at some point, how to prove that it is continuous at every point? (Darboux Weakening)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be Cauchy's functional equation i.e:

$$f(x_1 + x_2) = f(x_1) + f(x_2) \quad (1)$$

Wiki states that

> Cauchy proved that (1) is continuous. This condition was weakened in 1875 by Darboux who showed that it was only necessary for the function to be continuous at one point.

Let $f$ be continuous at let's say $0$ i.e:

$$ lim_{x\to0} f(x) = f(0) \quad (2)$$

How could we prove that $f$ is indeed continuous $ \forall x \in D(f)=\mathbb{R}$ based on (1) and (2)?

Comment: True, editing the question $D(f) = \mathbb{R}$. $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: My textbook and wiki stated this so I assume that it is true.

Comment: @bof Thank you, great answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is an additive function, i.e., it satisfies the additivity equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, and suppose $f$ is continuous at $a$; I want to show that $f$ is also continuous at $b$. Now
$$f(x)=f(x+a-b)+f(b-a)=f(g(x))+f(b-a)$$
where
$$g(x)=x+a-b.$$
Since $g$ is continuous at $b$ and $f$ is continuous at $g(b)$, it follows that $f\circ g$ is continuous at $b$; since $f(b-a)$ is a constant, it follows that $f(x)=f(g(x))+f(b-a)$ is continuous at $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ instead as $\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)$.